# Retrieve headlines and ratings from Reddit using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, reddit

I'm trying to get headlines and ratings from the reddit home page (www.reddit.com), and put them in to an array. At the moment it only retrieves one headline and I can't figure out  what to do to get it to retrieve all headlines and ratings from the page.

Currently I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.reddit.com/";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $var= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $third= stripos($var,'<p class="title"><a class="title " ',0);
    $fourth= stripos($var,'</span></p>',0);

    //echo substr($var,$first,$second-$first);
    echo substr($var,$third,$fourth-$third);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the reddit API?

Comment: @Fabian I'm not sure how to do that either, but I'd prefer to do it without using the reddit API.

Comment: may I ask why you don't want to use the API? Your problem would come down to getting 'http://www.reddit.com/.json' which contains all the content you want as a properly formed and easily accessible json (or xml if you prefer that)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regexp patterns, give it a try:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.reddit.com/";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $var= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    preg_match_all('/<a class="title " href="(.{0,255})" tabindex="1"(?:([\sa-z]+)="([a-z]+)")? >(.{0,255})<\/a>&#32;/', $var, $matches);
    print_r($matches[4]);
?>
```

Comment: Never occurred to me to use regex. Thanks. One thing though, how can I  add the rating for each headline in to the array (probably a 2d array)?

Comment: I'd like to ultimately be able to sort the headlines using their ratings, with the most voted ones are at the top.

Comment: You would have to change the regex or create a new one and compare to the titles. First check if that 2 arrays have the same length, then you can easily create new one based on that 2, with key as a rating and value as a title. Then using `ksort()` on it will sort your array by key. There you go.

Comment: I'm using the following to try to get ratings: '/<div class="score unvoted">(.-?[0-9]{1,10}\s*)<\/div>/' It works, but only a limited number of  ratings appear (there are 28 titles and only 24 ratings). I'm unsure how to link the two pieces of data also.

Comment: It's because some headers are not rated - some sponsoring is there.

Comment: how can I link the header and the ratings?

Answer (score 0):

When we are trying to fetch data from another site using curl, we will get response in                format "html string ".  So that we have to use DOMDocument to get value of html tags. 
Here I can successfully get headings text, look at following code :

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.reddit.com";
// Curl call to get heading tags
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST Data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$responseOfCurl = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());
if( curl_error($ch) )
{
 echo "<br> CURL ERROR: ".curl_error($ch);
}   
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($responseOfCurl);
// To get file src path from html response.
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($responseOfCurl);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$tags = $xpath->query("//p[@class='title']/a/@href|//p[@class='title']");   
$i=1;
$headingArray = array();
if(!empty($tags))
{
 foreach ($tags as $tag) 
 {    
  $redditHeading = "";
  $redditHeading = trim( $tag->nodeValue ); 
  $headingArray[].=$redditHeading;
 } 
  print_r($headingArray);
}
?>
```

Here I made query to get heading text as follows :
If you look view source of reddit.com page, you will get an idea that heading text is in     following format:

```
<p class='title'>
 <a class='title' href='abc.com'>heading text</a>
</p>
```

So that I made following query as  tag classname and

tag classname , 
"//p[@class='title']/a/@href|//p[@class='title']".

$headingArray In this array you will get all headings of reddit.com.
For cross checking, you put one heading from reditt.com and search in this array.

So, you have to make another query to get rating text from html tag.

Comment: I tried using the following query to get ratings: "//div[@class='score unvoted']" It doesn't seem to get all ratings, and I'm really not sure how headings and ratings can be linked. Would it be possible to put it in the array with the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You create an array and store respective headings and rating in that array.
Or you have to create combination of such query which will fetch Rating's and Heading's text. 
and stored it in array.